# Mapping VsCode bindings to work with e.keyCode | Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, keyboard, keymapping, vscode-keybinding

Recently I bought new Wireless Keyboard (Endorfy Thock) and where it works just fine while plugged by cable, the function keys (F1, F2, ..., F12) are working weirdly while keyboard is working in wireless mode

### Issue

Using `showkey` and `xev` I was able to identify the differences in keybindings between my Laptop Keyboard and my Wireless keyboard. The functionality and the keyCodes were different for my Wireless Keyboard, but with the usage of `xmodmap` command I'm able to bind proper functionalities to new keyCodes from my wireless keyboard

After this step, keyboard was working fine, but I found some issues in VSCode

### VSCode issue

I found out that the Functional Keys are not working properly in VSCode. In next steps I will focus on F3 that is used for highlighting, and searching this highlighted text in current file

`F3` was not working, and with the help of this [Keybinding Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues) article I was able to find the problem. I run the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` and here is the output for `F3` key for my Laptop, and my Wireless Keyboard

**Laptop** `F3`:

```
2023-11-26 12:36:42.357 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-11-26 12:36:42.357 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [F3]
2023-11-26 12:36:42.357 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 3 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.nextMatchFindAction, when: editorFocus, source: built-in.
2023-11-26 12:36:42.357 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F3, keyCode: 114, key: F3
2023-11-26 12:36:42.358 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F3, keyCode: 61 ('F3')
2023-11-26 12:36:42.358 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [F3]
2023-11-26 12:36:42.358 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 3 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.nextMatchFindAction, when: editorFocus, source: built-in.
2023-11-26 12:36:42.358 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.nextMatchFindAction
```

**Wireless Keyboard** `F3`:

```
2023-11-26 12:37:04.435 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-11-26 12:37:04.436 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-11-26 12:37:04.436 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: ShowAllWindows, keyCode: 114, key: F3
2023-11-26 12:37:04.436 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: ShowAllWindows, keyCode: 61 ('F3')
2023-11-26 12:37:04.437 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
```

**Code is different**: `F3` for Laptop, `ShowAllWindows` for Wireless Keyboard

---

I also tried to bind something for the Wireless Keyboard `F3` key, but VScode just see it as "unknown" and when I bind to it doesn't work
[unknown key binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCqRW.png)

In the [To sum up](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#to-sum-up) section:

```
On Windows, VS Code dispatches on e.keyCode.

On macOS and Linux, VS Code dispatches on e.code
```

we can see that VSCode, for Linux, bind the keys using the `code`, not the `keyCode`

### Questions

I think answering only on from the above questions will be sufficient for my case, but of course knowing answers to all will be super great

1. In Ubuntu, is it possible to change the `code` mapping for key?
2. How to make custom bindings using this `ShowAllWindows` code? I want it to behave exactly like the `F3` key from my Laptop
3. Can I make VSCode behave in such a way that for some of the bindings it will look at the `keyCode`, not the `code`?
   **EDIT:** We can make VSCode interpret `keyCode` instead of `code` by simply adding `"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"` in our
   settings.json